# OnTouch have view take up GONE views space?

Tags: android, view, screen

I have a webview and a adview and when I click on an item in the webview I want to hide the adview and make the webview take up the full screen.  I have the adview being hidden but then my webview actually shrinks some.  So I want to set it so it goes full screen when I click the item. I tried using the following in the on touch event but it just crashes the app.

```
                webview.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams(Gravity.FILL,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try with something like

> adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)

This should refresh your view.

Comment: I am doing that to hide my ad view.  I just need to set my webview which is above the ad view to take up the rest of the view.

Comment: You can close this question as it has been already solved.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Ashish answer with this

it will be better to add these views in FrameLayout

so that none of the both views will take space of each other

and then use

`adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`